Run-time error 13: type mismatch when looking for cells with a single space (non-blank cell)
I would like to find blank cells that contain a single space, then highlight all cells which have a single space.
Option Explicit

Sub blankWithSpace()
Dim rng As Variant

    For Each rng In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If rng.Value = " " Then
            rng.Style = "Note"
        End If
    Next rng
    
End Sub

Here is the message I get when attempting to run:

This is the expectation:
Before running the macro.

After running the macro.


Declare the variable as range type like Dim rng As Range.
